# Django Rest Framework: two viewsets for one router

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to have TWO DIFFERENT viewsets (for example, one implements only the GET method, the other implements only the POST method), but which will have the same url:
`GET /tournament/` - returns concrete object of the model Tournament;
`POST /tournament/` - create object of the model Tournament.

But it is important that they must have the same url `/tournament/`!

I trying something like this:

models.py

```py
class Tournament(Model):
    ...
```

viewsets.py

```py
class PublicTournamentEndpoint(
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = Tournament.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = []  # empty!

class PrivateTournamentEndpoint(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = Tournament.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = ['SomeAuthBackend']  # not empty!
```

routers.py

```py
class TournamentRouter(SimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/tournament/$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'post': 'create',
            },
            name='{basename}',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={},
        ),
```

urls.py

```py
tournament_router = TournamentRouter()
tournament_router.register(
    'tournaments',
    PublicTournamentEndpoint,
    basename='tournaments',
)

tournament_router.register(
    'tournaments',
    PrivateTournamentEndpoint,
    basename='tournaments',
)

urlpatterns += tournament_router.urls
```

But my `urlpatterns` has next values:

```py
[
    <URLPattern '^tournaments/tournament/$' [name='tournaments']>, 
    <URLPattern '^tournaments/tournament/$' [name='tournaments']>
]
```

and so when I send a `POST /tournament/` request, I get the following error:

```
405 "Method \"POST\" not allowed."
```

because the first match url does not have a POST method, but only GET. How can i resolve this problems?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call 2 views for 1 url. Seem like you only want to allow specific user who has `SomeAuthBackend` permission can create new `Tournament`, if so, you could custom your permission class a bit to check permission only on `POST` requests like so:

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

class SomeAuthBackend(permissions.BasePermission):
    protected_methods = ['POST',]
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in self.protected_methods:
            # Check permission here

        return True


class TournamentEndpoint(
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = Tournament.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = [SomeAuthBackend, ]  # empty!
```

With this, other method still works but when user send a `POST` request, it require to pass the permission check on `SomeAuthBackend`.

Comment: This is not only what I would like to do, everything is a little more complicated, but probably this is the only solution. Thank you!

Comment: It could be better if you could explain that complicated logic so that your question can be a good one, I'm also can give you an answer with all my best and then other people can refer it maybe.

Comment: The logic is not very complicated (quite large, many methods), but I would like to beautifully divide it into several viewsets, so that by looking at these viewsets it would be possible to tell which method from which viewsets the user can call (whether authorization or additional rights are needed). If I implement your solution (which I would like to avoid, but probably not), then someone will have to look at the code in SomeAuthBackend (this is not very convenient and obvious, in my opinion)

Comment: They can only need to take a look at the View when you override `create` method, I mean check permission inside that method then. But that is not the way Django Rest Framework refer. They separated the permission class to make it Single Responsibility. So if your permission name is good enough, other people just need to read the class name to understand the rest and don't even have to care about what permission class does and how you implemented it